# simple_form collection with string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm trying to set collection method for simple form, it works like this

```
def collection_input(attributes)
    options = "<option value = 1>enter text</option>"
    attributes.each do |attribute|
        if attribute == "selected"
            options = options + "<option value = '1' selected>#{attribute}</option>"
        else
            options = options + "<option value = '1'>#{attribute}</option>"
        end
    end
    options.html_safe
end
```

My result is almost what i need, except i get one extra 'option' with this `options` string literally put inside as value. i dont need that one:) How can i use simple_form collection with options as string?

EDIT

What i want:

```
<option value = '1'>enter text</option>
<option value = '0' selected>attr1</option>
<option value = '0'>attr2</option>
<option value = '0'>attr3</option>
<option value = '0'>attr4</option>
```

What i get:

```
<option value = "<option value = '1'>enter text</option>
<option value = '0' selected>attr1</option>
<option value = '0'>attr2</option>
<option value = '0'>attr3</option>
<option value = '0'>attr4</option>"></option>

<option value = '1'>enter text</option>
<option value = '0' selected>attr1</option>
<option value = '0'>attr2</option>
<option value = '0'>attr3</option>
<option value = '0'>attr4</option>
```

Comment: Your html syntax is broken - you should write eg `<option value="1" selected="selected">#{attribute}</option>"`

Comment: tried this approach, didnt help, i get the same result

Comment: Your explanation of the problem isn't clear.  Can you add (in an edit to your question) the html you actually get as a result of calling this method, and the html you **want** to get?

Comment: sure, give me a minute